# Rangy - selectNode() - different behaviour in different browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser, selection, rangy

I'm working with rangy and got a question relating to selection and its cross browser behaviour.

I've got some elements inside a div (e.g. a hyperlink) and I'd like to be able to select the **outerHTML** when clicking inside this element.

```
<div>Lorem ipsum <a href="#">duo dolores</a> tempor.</div>
```

So I tried `range.selectNode()` and expected the whole node to be selected so that `selection.toHtml()` would give me the outerHTML of the hyperlink. To get the innerHTML I would call `range.selectNodeContents()`. And this is how it works in IE 9.

But in Chrome in both cases only the innerHTML is being selected. Is there a bug in rangy plugin (which should be cross browser) or am I doing something wrong?

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNv83/5/) to see what I mean. First open it in IE 9, place the caret inside the hyperlink and click on the 1st button (check output of `selection.toHtml()`). Then place caret again inside the hyperlink and click on 2nd button (check output again). Afterwards do the same in Chrome.

Comment: Just found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442433/1794328). Is it still the same problem in my case?

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem. If you check the range after `selectNode()` you'll see that it has done what you expect; adding the range to the selection is what changes it.