# Range Selection HTML in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am Facing a problem in JavaScript to get html for selected text using 
    range for eg:-  i have an html like:-

```
  <span>demo text</span>
```

Now in Chrome when i select the "demo Text" then i want span tag with inner text.
I have tried the following code for that but not able to get the desired output in Chrome.

```
var rangeTemp = selection.getRangeAt(0);      
clonedSelection = rangeTemp.cloneContents();
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(clonedSelection);

word = div.innerHTML;
```

the Above code working fine in IE and Firefox but **not in chrome**.

Thanks & Regards

Anil

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: This is the same problem as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432933